# What are the individual bytes of WP7s ContentReadyEventArgs.ImageStream

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, stream, arrays, rgb

In a Windows Phone 7 app (and maybe 8, not sure), you can use the camera and retrieve the image the user captured. You do this with the [`ContentReadyEventArgs.ImageStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.contentreadyeventargs.imagestream%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property.

This gives you a stream which you can convert to an array. In my case, this array consists of negative integers.

I'm trying to found out what these integers represent (so I can manipulate them correctly).

Do they represent RGB values, or ARGB, or something else? Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentReadyEventArgs.ImageStream` contains the binary data of the JPG picture. So if you want to manipulate it, you'll have to load it in a [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) first. Then you can access the ARGB value of each pixel.